# Properties for Selenium Grid Hub/Node Config

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-grid

I'm going through a process of upgrading my Selenium Hub/Nodes to version 3.3. 
 Everything works fine, but I want to make sure I have optimal configuration... problem is I can't find a complete list of Hub/Node properties anywhere.

I've looked through:

- https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/grid.html
- http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json

These docs only list some of the properties through example configs, but none of them seem like a complete list and more importantly none of them actually state what these properties do.  **Where is the documentation for a complete list of configuration properties for Selenium Hub/Nodes?**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This documentation is available via the Selenium standalone uber jar itself.

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -help`

```
Usage: <main class> [options]
  Options:
    --version, -version
       Displays the version and exits.
       Default: false
    -browserTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to
       hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If the
       timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, the session
       will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means
       wait indefinitely.
       Default: 0
    -debug
       <Boolean> : enables LogLevel.FINE.
       Default: false
    -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
       <Integer> : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or
       negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.
    -log
       <String> filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will log
       to STDOUT
    -port
       <Integer> : the port number the server will use.
       Default: 4444
    -role
       <String> options are [hub], [node], or [standalone].
       Default: standalone
    -timeout, -sessionTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server
       automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X seconds. The
       test slot will then be released for another test to use. This is typically
       used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node roles, cleanUpCycle
       must also be set.
       Default: 1800
```

For help on the `hub` role

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role hub -help`

```
Usage: <main class> [options]
  Options:
    --version, -version
       Displays the version and exits.
       Default: false
    -browserTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to
       hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If the
       timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, the session
       will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means
       wait indefinitely.
       Default: 0
    -matcher, -capabilityMatcher
       <String> class name : a class implementing the CapabilityMatcher
       interface. Specifies the logic the hub will follow to define whether a request can
       be assigned to a node. For example, if you want to have the matching process
       use regular expressions instead of exact match when specifying browser
       version. ALL nodes of a grid ecosystem would then use the same capabilityMatcher,
       as defined here.
       Default: org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher@64a294a6
    -cleanUpCycle
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll running proxies
       for timed-out (i.e. hung) threads. Must also specify "timeout" option
       Default: 5000
    -custom
       <String> : comma separated key=value pairs for custom grid extensions.
       NOT RECOMMENDED -- may be deprecated in a future revision. Example: -custom
       myParamA=Value1,myParamB=Value2
       Default: {}
    -debug
       <Boolean> : enables LogLevel.FINE.
       Default: false
    -host
       <String> IP or hostname : usually determined automatically. Most commonly
       useful in exotic network configurations (e.g. network with VPN)
    -hubConfig
       <String> filename: a JSON file (following grid2 format), which defines
       the hub properties
    -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
       <Integer> : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or
       negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.
    -log
       <String> filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will log
       to STDOUT
    -maxSession
       <Integer> max number of tests that can run at the same time on the node,
       irrespective of the browser used
    -newSessionWaitTimeout
       <Integer> in ms : The time after which a new test waiting for a node to
       become available will time out. When that happens, the test will throw an
       exception before attempting to start a browser. An unspecified, zero, or negative
       value means wait indefinitely.
       Default: -1
    -port
       <Integer> : the port number the server will use.
       Default: 4444
    -prioritizer
       <String> class name : a class implementing the Prioritizer interface.
       Specify a custom Prioritizer if you want to sort the order in which new session
       requests are processed when there is a queue. Default to null ( no priority = FIFO
       )
    -role
       <String> options are [hub], [node], or [standalone].
       Default: hub
    -servlet, -servlets
       <String> : list of extra servlets the grid (hub or node) will make
       available. Specify multiple on the command line: -servlet tld.company.ServletA
       -servlet tld.company.ServletB. The servlet must exist in the path:
       /grid/admin/ServletA /grid/admin/ServletB
       Default: []
    -timeout, -sessionTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server
       automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X seconds. The
       test slot will then be released for another test to use. This is typically
       used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node roles, cleanUpCycle
       must also be set.
       Default: 1800
    -throwOnCapabilityNotPresent
       <Boolean> true or false : If true, the hub will reject all test requests
       if no compatible proxy is currently registered. If set to false, the request
       will queue until a node supporting the capability is registered with the grid.
       Default: true
    -withoutServlet, -withoutServlets
       <String> : list of default (hub or node) servlets to disable. Advanced
       use cases only. Not all default servlets can be disabled. Specify multiple on
       the command line: -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletA -withoutServlet
       tld.company.ServletB
       Default: []
```

For help on the `node` role

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role node -help`

```
Usage: <main class> [options]
  Options:
    --version, -version
       Displays the version and exits.
       Default: false
    -browserTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to
       hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If the
       timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, the session
       will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means
       wait indefinitely.
       Default: 0
    -capabilities, -browser
       <String> : comma separated Capability values. Example: -capabilities
       browserName=firefox,platform=linux -capabilities browserName=chrome,platform=linux
       Default: [Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5}], Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5}], Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=internet explorer, maxInstances=1}]]
    -cleanUpCycle
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll running proxies
       for timed-out (i.e. hung) threads. Must also specify "timeout" option
    -custom
       <String> : comma separated key=value pairs for custom grid extensions.
       NOT RECOMMENDED -- may be deprecated in a future revision. Example: -custom
       myParamA=Value1,myParamB=Value2
       Default: {}
    -debug
       <Boolean> : enables LogLevel.FINE.
       Default: false
    -downPollingLimit
       <Integer> : node is marked as "down" if the node hasn't responded after
       the number of checks specified in [downPollingLimit].
       Default: 2
    -host
       <String> IP or hostname : usually determined automatically. Most commonly
       useful in exotic network configurations (e.g. network with VPN)
    -hub
       <String> : the url that will be used to post the registration request.
       This option takes precedence over -hubHost and -hubPort options.
       Default: http://localhost:4444
    -hubHost
       <String> IP or hostname : the host address of the hub we're attempting to
       register with. If -hub is specified the -hubHost is determined from it.
    -hubPort
       <Integer> : the port of the hub we're attempting to register with. If
       -hub is specified the -hubPort is determined from it.
    -id
       <String> : optional unique identifier for the node. Defaults to the url
       of the remoteHost, when not specified.
    -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
       <Integer> : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or
       negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.
    -log
       <String> filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will log
       to STDOUT
    -maxSession
       <Integer> max number of tests that can run at the same time on the node,
       irrespective of the browser used
       Default: 5
    -nodeConfig
       <String> filename : JSON configuration file for the node. Overrides
       default values
    -nodePolling
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll to see if the
       node is still responding.
       Default: 5000
    -nodeStatusCheckTimeout
       <Integer> in ms : connection/socket timeout, used for node "nodePolling"
       check.
       Default: 5000
    -port
       <Integer> : the port number the server will use.
       Default: 5555
    -proxy
       <String> : the class used to represent the node proxy. Default is
       [org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy].
       Default: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
    -register
       if specified, node will attempt to re-register itself automatically with
       its known grid hub if the hub becomes unavailable.
       Default: true
    -registerCycle
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the node will try to register
       itself again. Allows administrator to restart the hub without restarting (or
       risk orphaning) registered nodes. Must be specified with the "-register"
       option.
       Default: 5000
    -role
       <String> options are [hub], [node], or [standalone].
       Default: node
    -servlet, -servlets
       <String> : list of extra servlets the grid (hub or node) will make
       available. Specify multiple on the command line: -servlet tld.company.ServletA
       -servlet tld.company.ServletB. The servlet must exist in the path:
       /grid/admin/ServletA /grid/admin/ServletB
       Default: []
    -timeout, -sessionTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server
       automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X seconds. The
       test slot will then be released for another test to use. This is typically
       used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node roles, cleanUpCycle
       must also be set.
       Default: 1800
    -unregisterIfStillDownAfter
       <Integer> in ms : if the node remains down for more than
       [unregisterIfStillDownAfter] ms, it will stop attempting to re-register from the hub.
       Default: 60000
    -withoutServlet, -withoutServlets
       <String> : list of default (hub or node) servlets to disable. Advanced
       use cases only. Not all default servlets can be disabled. Specify multiple on
       the command line: -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletA -withoutServlet
       tld.company.ServletB
       Default: []
```

Comment: omg can't believe I didn't find this before... thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you, a lot, one question, is it possible to disable the "grid/console" pages?

Comment: @ElheniMokhles The following servlets can be disabled via the parameter `-withoutServlet` : 1. `org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.beta.ConsoleServlet`, 2. `org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.LifecycleServlet`, 3. `org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.Grid1HeartbeatServlet`